# Displaying pre-formatted HTML content in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I have pre-formatted HTML content (from third Party) that I need to display in Ionic. For example, I have list of questions (pre-formatted html) that I get from DB which I need to display as a list of Ion-Items or Ion-Card in Ionic.

Sample HTML Content from DB:

First Record:

```html
<p>
<span style="color: #eb4924;"><strong>SOME_TEXT_HEADER 1</strong></span><br />
  TEXT_DESCRIPTION 1<br />
  <span style="color: #339966;"><strong>SOME_COMMENTS_HEADER:</strong></span><br />
  SOME_COMMENT_TEXT_1<br />
  SOME_COMMENT_TEXT_2<br />
  <img src="https://xyx.com/SOME_IMAGE.jpg" alt="ALT_TEXT" width="320" height="116"/>
  SOME_COMMENT_TEXT_3<br />
</p>
```

Second Record

```html
<p>
<span style="color: #eb4924;"><strong>SOME_TEXT_HEADER 2</strong></span><br />
  TEXT_DESCRIPTION 2<br />
  <span style="color: #339966;"><strong>SOME_COMMENTS_HEADER:</strong></span><br />
  SOME_COMMENT_TEXT_1<br />
  SOME_COMMENT_TEXT_2<br />
  <img src="https://xyx.com/SOME_IMAGE.jpg" alt="ALT_TEXT" width="320" height="116"/>
  SOME_COMMENT_TEXT_3<br />
</p>
```

Third Record:

```html
<p>
<span style="color: #eb4924;"><strong>SOME_TEXT_HEADER 3</strong></span><br />
  TEXT_DESCRIPTION 3<br />
  <span style="color: #339966;"><strong>SOME_COMMENTS_HEADER:</strong></span><br />
  SOME_COMMENT_TEXT_1<br />
  SOME_COMMENT_TEXT_2<br />
  <img src="https://xyx.com/SOME_IMAGE.jpg" alt="ALT_TEXT" width="320" height="116"/>
  SOME_COMMENT_TEXT_3<br />
</p>
```

...and so on

I want to get suggestions regarding best practices to handle this scenario. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can DomSanitizer from Angular, to display your html.

Html :

```
  <div class="details" [innerHtml]="details">
  </div>

</ion-content>
```

And in your ts :

```
 displayHTML(data){
        this.details = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(data);
 });
```

Don't forget to declare in the constructor :

```
public sanitizer: DomSanitizer
```